# How can I move cells with a background color based on specific conditions?

Tags: spreadsheet

[image]
Here is the initial position. I want to assign a script to the light blue rectangle to move cells with the #cc0000 color within the range in a specific direction by one cell at a time.

The movement logic is as follows:

1. Within the range (currently B19:S38 in the image), find cells colored with #cc0000 and store their positions in an array.
2. Calculate the distance between the recorded cell coordinates in W35 and the colored cells. (The distance is based on the position of the nearest cell to the target cell.)
3. If the movement needs to be horizontal or vertical, execute the script to move one cell in that direction.
4. If the movement involves both horizontal and vertical directions, move one cell in both horizontal and vertical directions.
   If the distance between the target cell and the colored cell is one cell, do not move and output a message saying 'Stop'.
5. The values within the cells remain unchanged during color movement. Reset the color of cells from the previous position, maintaining the color for overlapping cells.

If I click the button once from the initial image state, the cells marked in red will move to the positions shown in the image below.[image]

If you click the button again from that position, it will move vertically as shown in the image below.[image]

If there are red cells at that position, it will display 'Stop'.[image]

I attempted an AppScript implementation using my limited knowledge and ChatGPT, but it kept encountering errors and didn't function properly. Here's an example of the code I used.

```
function moveCellsByColor() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('B19:S36');
  var backgroundColors = range.getBackgrounds();
  var targetColor = '#cc0000';
  var rows = backgroundColors.length;
  var columns = backgroundColors[0].length;
  var coloredCells = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
      if (backgroundColors[i][j] === targetColor) {
        coloredCells.push({ row: i + 1, col: j + 1 });
      }
    }
  }

  var targetCell = sheet.getRange('W35').getValue();
  var targetRow = parseInt(targetCell.match(/\d+/)[0]);
  var targetColumn = targetCell.charCodeAt(0) - 65;
  var minDistance = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
  coloredCells.forEach(cell => {
    var distance = Math.abs(targetRow - cell.row) + Math.abs(targetColumn - cell.col);
    minDistance = Math.min(minDistance, distance);
  });
  if (minDistance === 1) {
    Logger.log('1 cell left, dont move.');
    return;
  }

  var cellsToMove = [];
  var cellsToKeep = [];

  coloredCells.forEach(cell => {
    var rowDiff = targetRow - cell.row;
    var colDiff = targetColumn - cell.col;

    var newRow = cell.row + (rowDiff !== 0 ? (rowDiff > 0 ? 1 : -1) : 0);
    var newCol = cell.col + (colDiff !== 0 ? (colDiff > 0 ? 1 : -1) : 0);

    if (newRow >= 1 && newRow <= rows && newCol >= 1 && newCol <= columns) {
      cellsToMove.push({ row: cell.row, col: cell.col });

      if (backgroundColors[newRow - 1][newCol - 1] !== targetColor) {
        cellsToKeep.push({ row: newRow, col: newCol });
      }
    }
  });
  cellsToMove.forEach(cell => {
    var moveCell = range.getCell(cell.row, cell.col);
    moveCell.setBackground(null);
  });

  cellsToKeep.forEach(cell => {
    var keepCell = range.getCell(cell.row, cell.col);
    keepCell.setBackground(targetColor);
  })
}
```

Comment: Thumbs up for the nice images. It looks all very interesting, but I don't think that a spreadsheet is the most appropriate "language" to code such a thing in?